# Use simple and double triple quote in groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have this code in groovy script:

```
script = ''' 
def val1 = 'val1' 
def val2 = 'val2' 
def cmd = """ cd /path/to/my/folder && python -c 'import MyClass; MyClass.my_method(\"${val1}\",\"${val2}\")' 
"""
def proc = ["bash", "-c", command].execute()
proc.waitFor()
print proc.in.text 
''';
```

I want to use parameter outside the script :

```
def val1 = 'val1' 
def val2 = 'val2' 
script = ''' 
def cmd = """ 
cd /path/to/my/folder && python -c 'import MyClass; MyClass.my_method(\"${val1}\",\"${val2}\")' 
""" 
def proc = ["bash", "-c", command].execute()
proc.waitFor()
print proc.in.text
''';
```

I try to combine simple and double triple quote but it is not working, do you have any idea how I can solve this problem ?

I want to use parameter outside the script :

```
def val1 = 'val1' 
def val2 = 'val2' 
script = """ 
def cmd = """ 
cd /path/to/my/folder && python -c 'import MyClass; MyClass.my_method(\"${val1}\",\"${val2}\")' 
""" 
def proc = ["bash", "-c", command].execute()
proc.waitFor()
print proc.in.text
""";
```

Comment: What do you mean "I want to use parameter outside the script"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this is what you need: triple double quotes on the outside to enable the placeholder replacement

```
def val1 = 'val1' 
def val2 = 'val2' 
script = """ 
    def cmd = '''
        if cd /path/to/my/folder; then
            python -c 'import MyClass; MyClass.my_method("${val1}","${val2}")' 
        fi
    '''
    def proc = ["bash", "-c", command].execute()
    proc.waitFor()
    print proc.in.text
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say for sure what you need but something like this is going to make more sense...

```
def val1 = 'val1' 
def val2 = 'val2'
def cmd = "cd /path/to/my/folder && python -c 'import MyClass; MyClass.my_method(${val1},${val2})'" 

script = """\
def proc = ["bash", "-c", ${cmd}].execute()
proc.waitFor()
print proc.in.text
"""
```

Maybe this if you really want the literal double quotes inside of your `cmd`...

```
def val1 = 'val1' 
def val2 = 'val2'
def cmd = "cd /path/to/my/folder && python -c 'import MyClass; MyClass.my_method(\"${val1}\",\"${val2}\")'" 

script = """\
def proc = ["bash", "-c", ${cmd}].execute()
proc.waitFor()
print proc.in.text
"""
```

I hope that helps.